# Calculation of equivalent resistance

Tags: resistors, thevenin, equivalent-circuit

I need to calculate the equivalent resistor between knots A and B to then use it in Thevenin Generator; it says the result should be (R // Zl) + (R // R) however I don't quite get why that's the case.

[image: picture of circuit containing 3 resistors and a coil]

Comment: Try to redraw the schematic in a "conventional form". Place the A-B terminals on the left, as a "voltage source would sit in between". Imagine the B-Terminal as beeing the circuit ground. Then simply add the missing R/L components according to the connections.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the equivalent resistance between A and B you have two serial connected resistors in parallel:

R+R || R+Zl

the formula for resistors in parallels is

R = R1*R2/(R1+R2),

or in your case:

R = ((R+R)(R+Zl))/(R+R+R+Zl) = 2R(R+Zl)/(3R+Zl)

Comment: The equation should be (R || Z) + (R || R), not as you have shown.  The top & bottom busses are shorted to get \$R_{th}\$. In the future, please use [MathJax](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering) markup to write your equations.

Comment: Hmm from the original drawing is not clear that there is a connection parallel of the R+L network, but if so you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to note is that the network has just three nodes (points that are not directly connected to one another).  One is A, one is B, and everything else is a single, connected node.  Let's call it C.  There is no part connected directly between A and B, everything goes via C.

So all we need to do is to determine the resistance between A and C, and then between C and B, and add them (those resistances are obviously in series).  A and C are connected with the two parts on the left, in parallel.  C and B are connected with the two parts on the right, in parallel.

That's essentially all there is.  The main thing is recognizing that there is just a single node in the network apart from A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Redraw the circuit and things become clearer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYSnwV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The answer should look something like this (I'll leave the derivation for you to work out):
$$ R_{AB} = {R \over 2} \left( {{3Z+R} \over {Z+R}} \right)  $$

Where \$Z\$ = the reactance of L1.

Comment: thank you sir,helps a lot